# Cannot create DAO instance from generic abstract singleton

Tags: java, class, generics, singleton, abstract

I have a class which I believe si a singleton, abstract and generic:

```
public abstract class GenericDaoImpl<E, K extends Serializable> implements GenericDao<E, K> {
private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;
private static ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry;

private final Class<? extends E> daoType = DaoTypeInit();
private static Class<?> DAO;

public static <T> T getDAO(Class<T> T) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
    if (DAO == null) {
        Class currentClass = new Object() { }.getClass().getEnclosingClass();
        DAO = (Class<?>)currentClass.newInstance();
    }
    return (T) DAO;
}
```

In the subclass that extends GenericDaoImpl it cannot seem to find getDAO although it is clearly there and inherited.

```
    StudentDaoImpl studentDAO = StudentDaoImpl.getDAO(Student.class);
```

What am I doing wrong, thanks?

Comment: Are you using java 8?

Comment: Yes Im using Java 8.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that get Dao is static !

```
public static <T> T getDAO
```

It should be :

```
public <T> T getDAO
```

Otherwise sub-classes won't have access to it unless they call it from the GenericDaoimpl class.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issue with this code but the main issue is that static methods and variables are not inherited, `new Object() { }.getClass().getEnclosingClass();` will always return GenericDaoImpl.class.

If you want a lazily initialized singleton instance you should declare it on the StudentDaoImpl.

Answer (score 0):

The current version of my code stands like this:

```
public abstract class GenericDaoImpl<E, K extends Serializable> implements GenericDao<E, K> {

private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;
private static ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry;    

private static final GenericDaoImpl DAO = BuildDAO(GenericDaoImpl.class);

public static <T extends GenericDaoImpl> T BuildDAO(Class<T> daoClazz) {
    sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();
    T newDao = null;
    try {
        newDao = daoClazz.newInstance();
    } 
    catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(daoClazz.getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }        
    return newDao;
}
```

It compiles and runs. Any comments, can you see any potential issues with this code?

Thanks